# Why won't postgres use a foreign key index?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, foreign-keys

Why would postgres refuse to use a foreign key? Here is my query, the join is on a foreign key.

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT *
FROM listings_searchresult
         JOIN listings_searchquery ON listings_searchresult.search_query_id = listings_searchquery.id
```

```
  Hash Cond: (listings_searchresult.search_query_id = listings_searchquery.id)
  ->  Seq Scan on listings_searchresult  (cost=0.00..4898345.08 rows=83607008 width=1129)
  ->  Hash  (cost=570499.88..570499.88 rows=20226788 width=109)
        ->  Seq Scan on listings_searchquery  (cost=0.00..570499.88 rows=20226788 width=109)
```

Why would postgres not use the foreign key? I delete it and readded it in case it was corrupted, still not working. Can I somehow force postgres to use this?

Comment: You have no `where` clause.  You are asking for all rows.  How do you think using an index stored separately from the rest of the columns of the `listings_searchresult` table and therefore require multiple, random-access seeks would help performance here?

Answer (score 1):

Unless one of the tables is very small, reading the whole tables is the most efficient technique to process such a query.

With a nested loop join, which is what you envision, PostgreSQL would have to scan an index on `listings_searchresult` 20 million times.

Using a hash join as it does, PostgreSQL builds a hash table in memory from the smaller table and probes that hash table for each row in the bigger table, which will perform better.

Joining two big tables without an additional `WHERE` condition is always going to be slow and can potentially produce a large result set.